# Two loops in ReactJS instead of hardcoding

Tags: javascript, loops, reactjs

I tried to accomplish extra exercises in [ReactJS tutorial Tic-tac-toe game](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Now I have this code:

```
class Board extends React.Component {
renderSquare(i) {
    return (
        <Square
            value={this.props.squares[i]}
            onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
        />
    );
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(0)}
                {this.renderSquare(1)}
                {this.renderSquare(2)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(3)}
                {this.renderSquare(4)}
                {this.renderSquare(5)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(6)}
                {this.renderSquare(7)}
                {this.renderSquare(8)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Instead of hardcoding `{this.renderSquare(x)}` for 9 times, I wanted to replace them with two loops or use `map(map())` but all that I write look worse than hardcoding it.

Is there a better way to do it and avoid hardcoding?

Comment: Take a look at [ask]. What 'looks worse'? How is it worse? Does it not work?  Etc. Edit your question to clarify accordingly. There's also https://codereview.stackexchange.com which might be a better venue for this kind of question.

Comment: Looks fine as it is.

Comment: Did you find any of the answers below useful? If yes, please consider up-voting them and "accept" the one that solved your issue (if any).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason using loops could be better is because a loop is more generic.

Here's some suggestions:

You can hold the amount of rows and squares per row in two variables that can serve as loop limits and then adjusting your grid will only require updating these two variables.

Splitting the code into a few methods might also clean it up.

Here's an example with loops:

```
// these can also be passed in as `props` 
// if you want to use them like `<Board totalRows={3} squaresPerRow={3} squares={...}/>`
const totalRows = 3;
const squaresPerRow = 3;

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    // ...
  }

  renderRow(row) {
    const squares = [];
    const offset = row * squaresPerRow; // this makes sure first row is 0,1,2, second row is 3,4,5, etc.
    for (let s = 0; s < squaresPerRow; s++) {
      squares.push(
        this.renderSquare(offset + s);
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="board-row">
        {squares}
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const rows = [];
    for (let r = 0; r < totalRows; r++) {
      rows.push(
        this.renderRow(r)
      );
    }
    return <div>{rows}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 maps, one that goes through each row and one that goes through each item in a row.

Since the items are just arbitrarily set as `0, 1, 2` etc, you can start off with just one array, and group them using `reduce()`.

This also allows you dynamically add rows, without having to specify them while also not requiring every row to contain 3 items.

---

Something like this:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      arr: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    };
  }

  renderSquare(item) {
    return <span>{item}</span>;
  }

  render() {
    let arr = this.state.arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
      let group = acc.pop();
      if (group.length == 3) {
        acc.push(group);
        group = [];
      }
      group.push(item);
      acc.push(group);
      return acc;
    }, [[]]);
    return ( 
      <div>
        {arr.map(group => {
          return (
            <div className="board-row">
              {group.map(item => this.renderSquare(item))}
            </div>
          );
        })
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("myApp"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp"></div>
```